# Events Calendar WP plugin -Change view depending on Screen Width

Tags: php, wordpress

We have a conflict somewhere on the Events calendar plugin by Modern Tribe mobile view which prevents clicking on events in the month mobile view.

In the mean time I found the php code to change the view from month to list when mobile is detected from Modern Tribe.

```
   add_action( 'template_redirect', 'tec_mobile_template_redirect' );
   function tec_mobile_template_redirect() {
   if( tribe_is_month() && wp_is_mobile() ) {
    wp_redirect( tribe_get_listview_link() );
    exit();
    }
```

One solution proposed was to do this but change to List view when a screen is at tablet and mobile size as well besides just when it detects its viewed on a device.  So we need to find a way to make it switch at media queries/breakpoints somehow.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: I think it would be easier if you load both view in a separate div. Hide the list view when screen is large. When the screen gets smaller display the list view and hide the other one. This can be achieved using only CSS.

Comment: Not entirely sure how I go about setting one of the plugins views as that for the WP plugin.

Comment: Obviously it'd be a media queries but to set it to show it as that view is what stumps me

Comment: It will be something like `@media (max-width: 767px) { .list{visibility: visible;}}` with the default visibility hidden. And `@media (min-width: 768px) { .full{visibility: hidden;}}` with the default visibility is visible for the other one. Something like that ?